# Want to exclude some data from ModelForm

Tags: python, django, forms, modelform

I try to make the form with objectl linked to only current base object (exclude others from their model):

**forms.py**

```
class RoomTypeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RoomType
        fields = {'Name', 'Rooms', 'Beds', 'Facilities', 'Capacity'}
        exclude = ('Building',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.building_id = kwargs.pop('building_id')
        self.fields['Capacity'].queryset = Capacity.objects.filter(
                                           Building=self.building_id
                                           )
```

**views.py**

```
def building_details(request, hotel_id, building_id):
    capacity_form = CapacityForm
    roomtype_form = RoomTypeForm
    args = {}
    args.update(csrf(request))
    args['building'] = Building.objects.get(id=building_id)
    args['capacity'] = Capacity.objects.filter(Building=building_id)
    args['roomtypes'] = RoomType.objects.filter(Building=building_id)
    args['capform'] = capacity_form
    args['rtform'] = roomtype_form(building_id=building_id)
    return render_to_response('building.html', args)
```

But I have the error:

> 'RoomTypeForm' object has no attribute 'fields'

in line:

> self.fields['Capacity'].queryset =
>   Capacity.objects.filter(Building=self.building_id)

How may it be possible to make all of this will be working? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `super()` class in `__init__`

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.building_id = kwargs.pop('building_id')
    super(RoomTypeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['Capacity'].queryset = Capacity.objects.filter(Building=self.building_id)
```

Or if you are using python3, you could just do:

```
super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Another side note, it is standard practice to specify a list or a tuple in the `fields`. You specified a set.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't works: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'building_id'

Comment: Move building_id above the super call